# Help Wiring Multiple 12 V Batteries for 24 V service

Tags: battery-charging

My question is: If you have 20 12 volt SLA 95 Ah batteries and you need to hook them up to a 24 volt inverter what is the best way to wire these batteries?

Right now I have them grouped in groups of 2 to make 24 volts and those 10 groups are wired in parallel with all matching cables running to a buss bar for the positive and one for the negative.

The charge controller from the solar panels is hooked to those buss bars. Then I have 2 positive and 2 negative cables all matched in length wired to my 8,000 watt PSW Inverter. Does this sound right?

Thanks

Comment: Any simple connection diagram for easy understanding?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds so far, so good.

A fuse in each 24v pair's connection to the buss might be useful, consider the failure mode should one battery go bad, and the others gang up on it (so to speak).